# How can I dynamically load a image in the body tag in each component?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-template

I am new at Angular, I have tried to create this example to make me understand. I would like that when I navigate from one component to another, I dynamically load the background image to the `body` tag, I do not know why it does not load.

In each component I include in the `styles` section, the image that I want to change for the body of each component.

Or what can I do? I just want to have a different background image for the components that are loaded in my router-outlet (in my case, mainComponent and anotherComponent)

This is my code:

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'another',
    template: '<a routerLink="/">main</a>',
    styles: [`body {
     position: fixed;
     min-width: 100%;
     background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080?landscape") !important;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100%;
     background-position: center;
     background-size: cover;
    }`]
```

second component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  template: '<a routerLink="/another">anotherComponent</a>',
  styles: [`body {
      position: fixed;
      min-width: 100%;
      background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080?stars") !important;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
}`]
```

This is the live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9kbx4q

Comment: I added better solution for your use case to my answer. Read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular you can not overwrite parent styles from components styles, because the styles of your component are encapsulated and works only for your component.

You should add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to `@Componentn({})`-definition in each component, where you want override css for body tag.

Here is an working example:

```
import { Component, Input , ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'another',
    template: '<a routerLink="/">main</a>',
    styles: [`body {
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080?landscape") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    }`],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AnotherComponent  {
  constructor(){}
}
```

**Important:** By disabling the encapsulation, you components styles are adopted global and will override styles with same classes, ids or tags.

**Hint:** You can use this solution, but it is better if you set background image to components own html tag.

**Better solution for your use case:**

Add an wrapper div to your `another` and `main` components template. Then add your styles to this wrapper div. Like this:

**another.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'another',
  template: '<div><a routerLink="/">main</a></div>',
  styles: [`div {
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080?landscape") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  }`]
})
```

**main.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  template: '<div><a routerLink="/another">anotherComponent</a></div>',
  styles: [`div {
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080?stars") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  }`]
})
```

Here is working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcxnln).

Read more about `ViewEncapsulation` on angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation).

Comment: @yavg Read my hint. If you need to override body tag from component styles, then it is only this way. In your case it is not best way. Best way is, when you set background image in each component on component tag/css-class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're trying to load the same background image into a component's template upon it's initialization?  Angular works off of template hierarchy, so common elements such as a background image should be implemented in higher level templates.  I would look at loading this image in the app.component template.

Comment: Or what can I do? I just want to have a different background image for the components that are loaded in my router-outlet

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood.  You can set the background image of any component the same way that you would on any HTML page.  Apply the background image to the top level <div> of the individual component, not to the body.  The <body> tag will apply to the entire application, just like with any other HTML web page.